# Which groups are reference groups in a regression model with interaction?

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, interaction, categorical-encoding

What are the reference groups in a regression model where there are interaction categories? Using the `iris` dataset in R, I've created a category with three levels from the `Sepal.Width` variable, and built a linear model with interaction:

```
data("iris")

iris$SW_cat = as.factor(ifelse(iris$Sepal.Width<3,0,
                     ifelse(iris$Sepal.Width<3.5,1,2)))

model1 = lm(data=iris, Sepal.Length ~ Species +
              SW_cat + Species*SW_cat)
```

`summary(model1)` returns the parameters from the model:

```
summary(model1)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = Sepal.Length ~ Species + SW_cat + Species * SW_cat, 
#>     data = iris)
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
#> -1.4381 -0.2539 -0.0381  0.2414  1.3619 
#> 
#> Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)
#>                           Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#> (Intercept)                4.45000    0.32564  13.666  < 2e-16 ***
#> Speciesversicolor          1.35294    0.33508   4.038 8.79e-05 ***
#> Speciesvirginica           1.88810    0.34079   5.540 1.42e-07 ***
#> SW_cat1                    0.40385    0.33793   1.195   0.2341    
#> SW_cat2                    0.78636    0.34012   2.312   0.0222 *  
#> Speciesversicolor:SW_cat1  0.01196    0.36564   0.033   0.9739    
#> Speciesvirginica:SW_cat1  -0.06886    0.36394  -0.189   0.8502    
#> Speciesversicolor:SW_cat2       NA         NA      NA       NA    
#> Speciesvirginica:SW_cat2   0.47554    0.44325   1.073   0.2852    
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 0.4605 on 142 degrees of freedom
#> Multiple R-squared:  0.7052, Adjusted R-squared:  0.6907 
#> F-statistic: 48.54 on 7 and 142 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Notably, the output is missing the following interactions:

- `Speciessetosa:SW_cat0`
- `Speciessetosa:SW_cat1`
- `Speciessetosa:SW_cat2`

Does this mean there are three reference groups in such an interaction model? I'm not sure how this can be the case, if a reference group is simply what the other terms are being compared to. Further, what is the interpretation of the intercept, give the model cannot take all three of these reference values at once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every categorical variable has a reference group. `Speciessetosa` is the reference group for `Species` and `SW_cat0` is the reference group for `SW_cat`.

The `Sepal.Length` for `Speciessetosa:SW_cat0` is the same as the `Intercept` (because both are reference groups, they are 'collapsed' into the intercept value).

The `Sepal.Length` for `Speciessetosa:SW_cat1` is the same as `Intercept` + the main effect `SW_cat1`.

The `Sepal.Length`for `Speciessetosa:SW_cat2` is the same as `Intercept` + the main effect `SW_cat2`.

Plotting the model results makes this much easier to follow.

Comment: I think I follow. Is `Speciessetosa:SW_cat1` not a reference group then?

Comment: @geoscience123 Sure, it's fair to think of it that way. I think of it as the intersection of the reference groups for each categorical variable. Functionally there's no difference between those interpretations.

Comment: (+1) @geoscience123 be careful, as the default choice of reference level for a categorical predictor can differ depending on the software you use. In R it's the lowest level, but in other software it can be the highest level. That can further confuse matters when there are interactions. When you're confused, trying things by hand and plotting data and model results can help clarify the situation.

Answer (score 2):

- note: I'm a *VERY* beginner, but I'll try to give you a hint. (if I'm wrong, please any moderator feel free to exclude this comment).

Whenever I have a complex model, I try to do the artimetic by hand, I find it really helpful. So, I'd begin with thinking that whenever we have a categorical variable with *n* levels, we would have *n-1 coefficients* for that variable.

- What's the reference level?

```
### The reference will be what appears first using levels():

levels(iris$SW_cat) ### 3 levels
levels(iris$Species) ### 3 levels

### Output:

> levels(iris$SW_cat) ### 3 levels
[1] "0" "1" "2"
> levels(iris$Species) ### 3 levels
[1] "setosa"     "versicolor" "virginica" 

### note that you can change the reference levels with fct_relevel()
```

- How are they coded?

Well, if you haven't made the constrasts yourself, then you should have the
dummy treatment constrast as this for both variables: [this link sounds helpful on visualizing it](http://dwstockburger.com/Multibook/Mlt07.htm)

```
contr.treatment(3)

### output: 

 2 3
1 0 0
2 1 0
3 0 1
```

With this in mind, you can think of what combinations refers to each levels of your variable (i.e, the X values in the equation), and the video linked below may help with it as well as the linked post above :)

- What I'd do next is to try to come up with the equation myself and then I'd plug in zeros and ones (dummy coding) to get a better perception of what's actually happening in the data.

[this video seems really helpful to understand the coefficient coding](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fDFyG_q2xQs)

`y = b0 + b1X1 + b1X1,2 + b2X2 + b2X2,2 + the interaction coefficients`

Here I stop because it's beyond my knowledge and I wanna help, not confuse you. So I'd take a look at [the first answer to this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/104677/how-many-parameters-in-this-specific-linear-model-with-interaction)in order to try to better understand how to write down the interaction parameters. My guts tell me that you'd have two: b3(X1 * X2) and b3 (X1,2 * X2,2). But I'm not sure about that, I'm sorry, but I hope this is at least a hint for you :)

Last but not least, [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dXPUBVGK6lE) deals with 2-level variables, but it has changed my life on how to interpret categorical*categorical interactions, so it may be helpful too

Comment: Thanks, I understand reference groups in non-interaction parameters. But I'm uncertain how to conceptualize them when interaction is involved.

Comment: The advice about working through simple versions of the problem by hand is pretty good, though ;-).